# How to refer to a bootstrap text field in vb code?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is my html code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname_txt" runat="server" placeholder="John" required maxlength="20"
                            data-validation-required-message="First Name is required" />
```

This is my VB code:
(Which is supposed to insert values into the database.)

```
Protected Sub page2_click(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles page2.Click
        con.Open()
        cmd = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO userinfo(fname, lname) VALUES('" & fname_txt.ToString() & "','" & lname_txt.ToString() & "')", con)
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
    End Sub
```

It executes just fine, without any compilation errors.
However, on checking the database,
The Values stored within cells is- 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText'.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you need to (at least) escape ' in your html code or use parameters in your oledbcommand. otherwise your insert command is vulnerable for bugs

Comment: just a tip if you aren't going to use parameters, which you should. You should change each of your values you are inserting to fname_txt.Value.ToString().Replace("'","''") which will allow you to submit single quotes in the textbox by doubling them up. Currently the way your code is written if someone puts a single quote it'll break your sql string fname_txt.Value = Michael's. You're Insert would be INSERT INTO userinfo(fname, lname) VALUES('Michael's','Jones') in order for SQL Server to process if needs to be received as INSERT INTO userinfo(fname, lname) VALUES('Michael''s','Jones')

Comment: @SeanWessell, absolutely. Didn't occur to me. You're right. Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fname_txt.ToString()` will give `'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText'.` so use  `fname_txt.Value` instead for that.

So your Query command will be:

```
  cmd = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO userinfo(fname, lname) VALUES('" & fname_txt.Value & "','" & lname_txt.Value & "')", con)
```

Comment: It returns the following error:

BC30456: 'Text' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText'.

Comment: Actually, in vb.net you use the .text property

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal with asp.net Textbox you would use the .text property (System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox) with System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText you need to use the .value property as there is no .text property

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlinputtext(v=vs.110).aspx       VS     https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx